Facebook Developer Reoccurring Notifications (Marketing Message) not eligible for IG beta?
I tried sending an opt-in on Instagram from my creator IG account to my personal IG account to Reoccurring Notifications (Marketing Message). I received the error "(#10) This account is not eligible for the Recurring Notification IG Beta". I have the messaging permission, my app passed App Review, I can send normal messages but its just marketing messages that don't work.
On other forums, people say the beta was supposed to end late 2022. Is anyone able to send these opt In messages without being in the beta program? Is the beta program still a thing? Does anyone have any updates on this?
I sent post request to messaging api with "template_type":"notification_messages" and expected to send an opt-in template message but instead received error saying I'm not eligible for IG beta program.

...longshot but did you happen to figure this out?
